# Is Nebula 9 a real (or maybe inspired) show?

Tags: analysis, castle

In Episode 6 of Season 5 of [Castle](http://beta.abc.go.com/shows/castle) ('**Final Frontier**'), there is a murder, wherein the body is placed inside a fake spaceship designed for the '**Nebula 9** Fan Experience'.
I Googled *Nebula 9* and all results are abc.com or *Memes* released by it.

I'm pretty convinced that it's made-up, but just wanted to confirm it is.
And if it is made-up, was it inspired by some long-forgotten failed Sci-Fi show?
If yes, *which one*?!

Comment: I don't have 150 rep so I can't create tags but there doesn't seem to be one for Castle.
Could someone please create _castle_

Comment: There are actually 14 episodes of Firefly, not 12. However, that is the only show I recognized a reference to... other than the obvious mentions of Star Trek.

Comment: One other nod in Castle to firefly is Commander Walsh.

Comment: Completely aware this question is getting old, but the Nebula 9 setup reminded me somehow to Blake's 7.

Comment: The costumes and the episode title clearly point to Star Trek.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd say *Nebula 9* was a nod to [***Firefly***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0303461/), but there were a lot of references to other Sci-Fi shows as well.

From [**Le Geek**](http://iheartlegeek.com/2012/11/07/castle-final-frontier-geeky-references/):

> **Firefly** references:
>
> - *Nebula 9's* Captain is called **Max Reynard**, in *Firefly* the name was **Mal Reynolds**
> - **Lt. Chloe** in *Nebula 9*, **Zoe** in *Firefly*
> - **Creavers** in *Nebula 9*, **Reavers** in *Firefly*
> - *Nebula 9* was cancelled *"over a decade ago, and only had 12 episodes at that"*
> - Castle says "Shiny" a common phrase in Firefly for 'good' or 'cool'
> - Castle [also says](http://www.tv.com/shows/castle/the-final-frontier-2577968/): *"I'm a fan of good sci-fi. StarTrek, Battlestar, **that Joss Whedon show**,..."*

**Star Trek** references:

> - [Jonathan Frakes](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000408/) *(William T. Riker)* not only directed the episodes, he also has a cameo.
>
>   [image: Frakes] <sup>[[Source](http://screenrant.com/castle-season-5-episode-5-final-frontier-recap/)]</sup>
> - [Armin Shimerman](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001734/) *(Quark)* also made an appearance
>
>   [image: Shimerman] <sup>[[Source](http://castleconvention.com/castle-convention-guest-actor-announcement-minor-spoiler-for-mondays-episode/1326)]</sup>
> - Castle is doing a **Captain Kirk impersonation**
> - Castle is doing a **Captain Picard impersonation**

*(Click the 'Le Geek' link for more references to other Sci-Fi shows, movies and fan culture)*

Comment: and also nathan fillion who plays Castle also played Mal Reynolds in firefly

Comment: @Keegan And that's the ultimate reference and the reason why it *had* to be *Firefly* (in fact I immediately thought about *Firefly* when reading *"reference to SciFi show"* and *"Castle"* in one question, without having seen the mentioned *Castle* episode). Oliver_C should add your point into the answer.

Comment: Technically, I wouldn't count _Nathan Fillion's_ mere appearance in this particular episode as a *Firefly* reference because he appears in __every__ episode of _Castle_. Had he shown up in his ['space cowboy' costume](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0g42UxfB6MI) again, it would have certainly made the list though ;)

Comment: @Oliver_C *"Technically, I wouldn't count Nathan Fillion's mere appearance in this particular episode as a Firefly reference because he appears in every episode of Castle"* - Of course not, but it is when the said episode is otherwise filled with various references to scifi-shows, which not every *Castle* episode is. At least it's worth a mention in the answer even if not advertised directly as *"intentional reference"*.

Comment: And the name *Nebula 9* itself is a play on Babylon 5.